# "Etymology" of symbols for injections and surjections

Tags: functions, notation, terminology

Excuse me if this sounds silly. Does anybody know why injections and surjections are sometimes denoted symbolically as $f:V\hookrightarrow W$ and $g:V\twoheadrightarrow W$? How do the arrows $\hookrightarrow$ and $\twoheadrightarrow$ convey the meanings of injections and surjections?

Comment: I like to think $\hookrightarrow$ is reminiscent of the $\subset$ symbol, and $\twoheadrightarrow$ looks like two things being stacked, so like a quotient. I think that [Quillen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category) used $\rightarrowtail$ for injections (monomorphisms really) instead.

Comment: @MikePierce How is the symbol $\subset$ related to injection?

Comment: @user1551 If $A\subset B$, then $a\mapsto a$ is an injection

Comment: @MikePierce Hmm, but the definition of injection doesn't require the domain and codomain to live in the same ambient space...

Comment: Sure, but it's just an analogy. Given $\phi\colon A \hookrightarrow B$, then $A \simeq \mathrm{Im}\phi \subset B$. Generally you can define injections without any sort of *ambient* space, but they're kinda like picking out subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think $\hookrightarrow$ is reminiscent of the $\subset$ symbol, which is apt since if you have $i\colon A \hookrightarrow B$, then $A \simeq \operatorname{Im}i \subset B$. An injective map is *kinda like* picking out a subset. I think that Quillen used ↣ for injections (monomorphisms really) instead. For surjective maps $\twoheadrightarrow$ looks like two things being stacked, so like a quotient.

Answer (score 1):

The curved arrow makes me think of an inclusion, which is appropriate to figure an injection ; the double arrow seems to mean that the mapping really reaches the arrival domain, which is appropriate to figure a surjection.